# Why is my text is aligned vertically center in my input[type="text"]? Why are my sectoins wrapping on each other? Why is my body is overflowing in X?

Tags: html, css, input

I have 3 problems and no idea of how to fix them.

The First is that when I type in the input the text is aligned vertically in the last `input[type='text']` in the `.discounts` section

The Second is the `.discounts` section and the `.footer` section are being on each other for no reason

The Third is that there is an x overflow in the website. However, I have put `overflow: hidden;` on the body already and I can't see any element overflowing out of the body

My Codepen :

https://codepen.io/Romany-Refaat/pen/MWPRRoG

At the First problem, I tried adding

```css
display: flex;
align-items: flex-start;
```

to the input but nothing has changed

At the Second problem, I tryed adding `margin-bottom` to `.discounts` section but it obviously not responsive.

At the Third problem, I have taken a deep look at each section in chrome dev tools but I unfortunately have no idea of where the problem is

Comment: First and foremost, please edit to include a [mre]; links to external sites may be inaccessible and/or rot at any time. Regarding your problems: (1) That's because it's an `<input>`. If you want multiline (which is more suitable for this kind of input), use a `<textarea>`. (2) The items in the `.team` section is not responsive; their `::before`s no longer fit their parents the screen shrinks and therefore cause the overflow. (3) You are limiting `.discount .container-grid` to a `height` of `100vh` and enforcing `overflow: hidden` on `.discount`.